# WPF: Programatically Animate Rectangle Color in Grid

Tags: c#, wpf, animation

How can I programatically change the Color of a Rectangle in my Grid?

```
        ColorAnimation myColorAnimation = new ColorAnimation();
        myColorAnimation.From = Colors.Red;
        myColorAnimation.To = Colors.Blue;
        myColorAnimation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500));
        myColorAnimation.AutoReverse = false;

        myStoryboard = new Storyboard();
        myStoryboard.Children.Add(myColorAnimation);
        Storyboard.SetTargetName(myColorAnimation, ?); // What do I put here
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(myColorAnimation, new PropertyPath //What do I put here?
```

Comment: can you show the xaml code for your rectangle and the grid it's placed in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found a way to do this:

I create a StoryBoard for each Grid item:

```
    List<Storyboard> _animatableGridRectToGray = new List<Storyboard>();
    List<Storyboard> _animatableGridRectToWhite = new List<Storyboard>();
```

and populate:

```
private void initAnimatableGridRectangles()
{
    int index = 1;
    foreach (Rectangle rect in SequenceGrid.Children)
    {
        SolidColorBrush tempBrush = new SolidColorBrush();
        rect.Fill = tempBrush;
        string brushName = "Brush" + index;
        _gridBrushes.Add(brushName, tempBrush);
        this.RegisterName(brushName, tempBrush);

        Storyboard tempSBToGray = new Storyboard();
        Storyboard tempSBToWhite = new Storyboard();
        ColorAnimation tempColAnimToGray = getAnimToGray();
        ColorAnimation tempColAnimToWhite = getAnimToWhite();
        tempSBToGray.Children.Add(tempColAnimToGray);
        tempSBToWhite.Children.Add(tempColAnimToWhite);
        Storyboard.SetTargetName(tempColAnimToGray, brushName);
        Storyboard.SetTargetName(tempColAnimToWhite, brushName);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(tempColAnimToGray, new PropertyPath(SolidColorBrush.ColorProperty));
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(tempColAnimToWhite, new PropertyPath(SolidColorBrush.ColorProperty));
        _animatableGridRectToGray.Add(tempSBToGray);
        _animatableGridRectToWhite.Add(tempSBToWhite);
        index++;
    }
}


private ColorAnimation getAnimToGray()
{
    ColorAnimation colAnim = new ColorAnimation();
    colAnim.To = Colors.Gray;
    colAnim.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500));
    colAnim.AutoReverse = false;
    return colAnim;
}

private ColorAnimation getAnimToWhite()
{
    ColorAnimation colAnim = new ColorAnimation();
    colAnim.To = Colors.White;
    colAnim.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500));
    colAnim.AutoReverse = false;
    return colAnim;
}
```

Then I can animate like so:

```
_animatableGridRectToGray[index].Begin(this);
```